# Non admin user to create and delete task programmatically

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-7-x64

I am trying to query,create and delete  a task in C# through schtasks.exe as a process.

As an administrator everything works fine but when run as non-admin user, I get access denied message. I tried giving user permission on C:\Windows\System32\Tasks folder through Calcs.

Also tried giving permission to start and stop service through SubInAcl /Service Schedule /Grant=DOMAIN\nonadminuser=TO

Error: OpenService Error:5 Access is denied.

User cannot be a power user or Backup Operators.

Let me know if there is anything that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

could you impersonate an admin user when creating the task?

[Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also there is a .NET wrapper for the task scheduler - [Task Scheduler Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) which may be easier to use the the command line version you are using, not sure if it would help with the access denied issue though.

Comment: For those coming here and wondering, the Task Scheduler Wrapper will NOT help with the access denied issue.